# SQL-Count para cada id

Tags: sql, count

Eu pretendo mostrar todos os registos da tabela aluno - nome e o número - e depois na coluna à direita, mostrar a percentagem de assiduidade. Vejamos:

```
SELECT nome, numero, (
(

SELECT COUNT(aluno.numero)
FROM aluno
JOIN aula ON aluno.id_aula_aluno = aula.id_aula 
WHERE aula.id_uc_aula =4
AND aula.id_professor_aula =1 AND aluno.numero=11111) / 

(SELECT COUNT( aula.id_uc_aula )
FROM aula
WHERE aula.id_uc_aula =4
AND aula.id_professor_aula =1 )
) AS Percentagem

FROM aluno
JOIN aula
WHERE aula.id_uc_aula =4
AND aula.id_professor_aula =1
AND aluno.id_aula_aluno = aula.id_aula
```

Ou seja, no segundo select so esta a ser contabilizado para um aluno e eu queria para cada id automaticamente. A divisão esta entre os dois select.

Comment: O que significa id_uc_aula?

Comment: Não sei bem o que você ainda esta querendo fazer, mais duas coisas importantes para se ver, 1º no seu segundo select você tem um `COUNT( aula.id_uc_aula )` e depois `WHERE aula.id_uc_aula =4` isso no máximo ira retorna 1 no seu ` Count`  2º existe a necessidade de você verificar se o segundo select não retorna um valor `null` , se isso acontece vai retorna um erro de divisão [veja aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861778/how-to-avoid-the-divide-by-zero-error-in-sql)